# Regex Matching and Deleting/Replacing a string

Tags: regex, vb.net

So I am trying to parse through a file which has multiple "footers" (the file is an output that was designed for printing which my company wants to keep electronically stored...each footer is a new page and the new page is no longer needed as).

I am trying to look for and remove lines that look like:

1 of 2122                            PRINTED 07/01/2013 04:46     Page   : 1 of 11
2 of 2122                            PRINTED 07/01/2013 04:46     Page: 2 of 11
3 of 2122                            PRINTED 07/01/2013 04:46     Page: 3 of 11

and so on

I then want to replace the final line (which would read something like "2122 of 2122") with a "custom" footer.

I am using RegEx, but am very new to using it so how should my RegEx look in order to accomplish this? I plan on using the RegEx "count" function to find out when I've found the last line and then do a .replace on it.

I am using VB .NET, but can translate C# if required. How can I accomplish what I'm looking to do? Specifically I only care about matching/removing of a match so long as the # of matches > 1.

Comment: Show us what you've done so far so we can see the effort you've already put into it and where you're getting stuck.

Comment: Does the footer exist on it's own line? That could help with the correct Regex. As for removing each match, you could do a `regex.replace` and replace your match with an empty string... Post more data and we might be able to help....

Comment: @JohnBustos

Yes they do. I've shown the format, but the # of pages can change and it may be at different locations in the overall file. These files are designed to be printed, not stored electronically. So they contain a lot of printer control characters which are removed prior to the footer formatting.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's one](http://regexr.com?35hds) I created with RegExr:

```
/^(\d+\s+of\s+\d+)(?=\s+printed)/gim
```

It matches (number)(space)('of')(space)(number) at the beginning of a line, and only if it is followed by (space)('printed'), case insensitive. The /m flag turns ^ and $ into line-aware boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up doing it...

```
Private Function FixFooters(ByVal fileInput As String, Optional ByVal numberToLeaveAlone As Integer = 1) As String
    Dim matchpattern As String = "^\d+\W+of\W+\d+\W+PRINTED.*$"
    Dim myRegEx As New Regex(matchpattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline)
    Dim replacementstring As String = String.Empty
    Dim matchCounter As Integer = myRegEx.Matches(fileInput).Count
    If numberToLeaveAlone > matchCounter Then numberToLeaveAlone = matchCounter
    Return myRegEx.Replace(fileInput, replacementstring, matchCounter - numberToLeaveAlone, 0)
End Function
```

I used myregextester.com to get the inital matchpattern. Since I wanted to leave the last footer alone (to manipulate it further later on) I created the numberToLeaveAlone variable to ensure we don't remove ALL of the variables. For the purposes of this program I made the default value 1, but that could be changed to zero (I only did it for readability in the calling code as I know I will ALWAYS want to leave one...but I do like to reuse code). It's fairly fast, I'm sure there are better ways out there, but this one made the most sense to me.